# Does Amazon Cognito support the 'address' scope? It appears to be missing

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito, openid-connect

I've got an issue with a third-party application whereby they're allowing OpenID Connect as an identity source but they appear to be passing an invalid scope across in the request which is causing us issues. The third-party's response to us is frustratingly "nobody else has told us this is a problem" so we're not getting very far on that front so I thought I'd ask here to see if anyone can help either point to a potential work-around or give me some clear information to provide back to the third-party. The scenario is...

1. The third-party application redirects to `https://myapplication.auth.eu-west-2.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&redirect_uri=https://myapplication.com/auth/oidc&scope=openid profile email phone address&response_type=code&state=std`
2. Cognito redirects to `https://myapplication.com/auth/oidc?error_description=invalid_scope&state=std&error=invalid_request`

The problem is in `scope=openid` profile email phone address parameter. There is no `address` scope in Cognito. If the third-party application redirected to...

`https://my-application.auth.eu-west-2.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&redirect_uri=https://myapplication.com/auth/oidc&scope=openid%20profile%20email%20phone&response_type=code&state=std`

... instead (no `address` scope), everything would work fine.

It's worth noting that we do have Address ticked under Attributes in the Cognito UI and custom scopes won't work as we need the scope to be "address" in this case specifically as that's what the app asks for. I have noticed that the "Allowed OAuth Scopes" section in the Cognito UI only lists the "phone", "email", "openid", "aws.cognito.signin.user.admin" and "profile" scopes, I don't know why that is but it's either down to Cognito or the standard I'm assuming.

Also, we tried using the Cognito Lambda pre-token generation trigger but we still see the same result so it appears that the trigger hasn't fired since the request was thrown out as invalid first.

Any help you can give is appreciated.

Thanks in advance, Ash.

Answer (score 0):

Its up to the identity provider to decide what scopes to support. If you use services like Auth0 or product like IdentityServer, its up to the developer to choose what scopes to support. Even if it is part of the standard set of scopes.